# my polygon stretched out when sculpitng?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, sculpt, zbrush

[image]
Hi, I'm working on this 3d sculpt in blender and Im having this issue on the arm where the lines get streched if you see the torso it looks fine but the arm is messed up. I pulled the arm out. I'm gussing that it could be because of the polygon count if so how do I increase the count in that specific area, new to sculpting. is there a setting that I missed and Im not using dynamic topology im using remash, tried using dt but syaing I got an vertex error or something.

Thanks!

Comment: you must have stretched this part with one of the brushes, maybe give a correction to this area with dyntopo and mesh collapse

Comment: In the tutorial I was watching she pulled the forearm out using the move tool. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-gSVS4E6zk at 15:29

Comment: Sorry this one i mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xypvsf94onc

Comment: yes it looks like she stretches her topology, maybe you stretched too much or you don't have as much topology, but I'm not sure why she uses this method, why don't you use dyntopo at least on this part in order to add topology?

Comment: I tried but I get an warning saying Vertex data detected and it slows down my computer and doesnt work

Comment: does the message prevent you to use Dyntopo? Also make sure that the Dyntopo Detail Size is not too low? If you don't want to use Dyntopo, I guess you need to cut this part or use Remesh

Comment: you can also simply boolean with a another object

Comment: I don't know what you mean by boolen but I just cut the arm off and used a cylinder instead of streatching it

Comment: Boolean is a modifier, you can create another object and add it (Union) to your object